# Preserving carriage return (\r, \n) information when decoding information

Tags: ios, swift, base64, sha256

I have to decode from base64 a string. In there there is a SHA256 Digest:

```
MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEILkTxTJ4rAzOn3HeT5m19lcvbR4S3J10jmmAcYuc&#xD;\rnp58<
```

But after decoding it it becomes

```
MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEILkTxTJ4rAzOn3HeT5m19lcvbR4S3J10jmmAcYuc&#xD;
np58<
```

How can I preserve the carriage return when decoding?

The code I am using for decoding:

```swift
    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        var st = self;
        let remainder = self.count % 4
        if remainder > 0 {
            st = self.padding(toLength: self.count + 4 - remainder,
                                          withPad: "=",
                                          startingAt: 0)
        }

        
        guard let d = Data(base64Encoded: st, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else{
            return nil
        }
      
        return String(data: d, encoding: .utf8)
    }
```

Comment: Why do you specify `ignoreUnknownCharacters` if you want to keep the line ending characters? From the documentation: *Modify the decoding algorithm so that it **ignores** unknown non-Base-64 bytes, **including line ending characters.***

Comment: Is the first string in your question supposed to be in base64? I don’t think a valid base64 encoding would include characters other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `+`, `/` and `=`. I think you might be seeing some some of url/html encoding issue in the way you get your alleged base64 string.